# Java Regex : String Formatting

Tags: java, regex, string

After runing this

```
Names.replaceAll("^(\\w)\\w+", "$1.")
```

I have a String Like

```
Names = F.DA, ABC, EFG
```

I want a String format like

```
F.DA, A.BC & E.FG
```

How do I do that ?

Update :

If I had a name Like

`Robert Filip, Robert Morris, Cirstian Jed`

I want like

```
R.Filp, R.Morris & C.Jed
```

I will be happy, If also you suggest me a good resource on JAVA Regex.

Comment: Well, it works fine. Are you testing the regex on some other string?

Comment: So you want to replace the last comma with an `&`?

Comment: For me It's not working.

Comment: @assylias yes, I want to replace the ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you:

```
 String names = "Robert Filip, Robert Morris, Cirstian Jed, S.Smith";
 String repl  = names.replaceAll("((?:^|[^A-Z.])[A-Z])[a-z]*\\s(?=[A-Z])", "$1.")
                     .replaceAll(", (?=[^,]*$)", " & ");

 System.out.println(repl); //=> R.Filip, R.Morris, C.Jed & S.Smith
```

**Explanation:**

1. 1st `replaceAll` call is matching a non-word && non-dot character + a capital letter in group #1 + 0 or more lower case letters + a space which should be followed by 1 capital letter. It is then inserting a dot in front of the match `$1.`
2. 2ns `replaceAll` call is matching a comma that is not followed by another comma and replacing that by literal string `" & "`.

Comment: But, If I had a name Like Robert Filip, Robert Morris, Cirstian Jed. I want like R.Filp, R.Morris & C.Jed ??

Comment: You solution wroked.But Can you answer my question.

Comment: @user2579475: Its better to provide realistic inputs in the question. Anyway I will edit my answer to suite your example names.

Answer (score 6):

You need to re-assign the result back to `Names`, since *Strings* are immutable, the `replaceAll` methods does not do in place replacement, rather it returns a new String:

```
names = names.replaceAll(", (?=[^,]*$)", " & ")
```

Comment: @user2579475. Now you need to show us the full code, as this is working on my Computer. There is no reason it can't work on your given String. There is something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: getName.replaceAll("^(\\w)\\w+", "$1.").replaceAll(", (?=[^,]*$)", " & "));

Comment: @user2579475. Umm. Can you show your original String. It seems like your 1st `replaceAll` is the culprit. It doesn't give you the String which you have shown in the question. And please add the code to the question.

Comment: @user2579475. Print the output of `getName.replaceAll("^(\\w)\\w+", "$1.")` to see it gives the same string as in your question. I bet it doesn't.

Comment: @user2579475. See, your first replaceAll doesn't give what you thought it gave. Change it to: `getName.replaceAll("^(\\w)(\\w+)", "$1.$2")`

Comment: Same behavior. It change only the 1st character.

Comment: @RohitJain Notice the **^** (\\w)(\\w+).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String names = "Amal.PM , Rakesh.KR , Ajith.N";
    names = names.replaceAll(" , (?=[^,]*$)", " & ");
    System.out.println("New String : "+names);
```